# Creating a multi-color bar using CSS

Tags: css

I would like to create a multi-color bar like the one in the picture below:

[image]

Is it possible to create CSS that will achieve this? I've managed to create the color gradients using the following CSS:

```
.gold{
  background-color: #faa732;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eab92d, #c79810);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#eab92d), to(#c79810));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eab92d, #c79810);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eab92d, #c79810);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eab92d, #c79810);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffbb450', endColorstr='#fff89406', GradientType=0);
}

.blue {
  background-color: #faa732;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #034a96, #0663c7);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#034a96), to(#0663c7));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #034a96, #0663c7);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #034a96, #0663c7);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #034a96, #0663c7);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffbb450', endColorstr='#fff89406', GradientType=0);
}

.green {
  background-color: #faa732;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0D7626, #0a611e);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0D7626), to(#0a611e));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0D7626, #0a611e);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0D7626, #0a611e);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0D7626, #0a611e);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffbb450', endColorstr='#fff89406', GradientType=0);
}
```

I'm just not sure how to make them appear next to each other like in the picture and also how to have different percentage widths (e.g. blue gradient 50% of the bar, green gradient 40%, and gold gradient 10%).

Comment: What part? The gradient? Do you have any markup to start with?

Comment: What "it"? What "this"? Post HTML and CSS you've tried.

Comment: Mocking up your imaginations here wont help u a lot..paste some code here

Comment: "How" is this stacked? How should it behave if the screen would be made wider, or less wide? Do you want three bars that overlap? Do they even need to overlap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements. They add content to the beginning and end **inside** the given selector.

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  height: 2em;

  background-color: #faa732;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eab92d, #c79810);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#eab92d), to(#c79810));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eab92d, #c79810);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eab92d, #c79810);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eab92d, #c79810);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffbb450', endColorstr='#fff89406', GradientType=0);
}

div:before {
  height: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  float: left;

  background-color: #faa732;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #034a96, #0663c7);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#034a96), to(#0663c7));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #034a96, #0663c7);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #034a96, #0663c7);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #034a96, #0663c7);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffbb450', endColorstr='#fff89406', GradientType=0);
}

div:after {
  height: 2em;
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  float: right;

  background-color: #faa732;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0D7626, #0a611e);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0D7626), to(#0a611e));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0D7626, #0a611e);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0D7626, #0a611e);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0D7626, #0a611e);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffbb450', endColorstr='#fff89406', GradientType=0);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Demo: http://jsbin.com/umaden/3/edit

PS In real usage you should apply this to a class or id, not an element selector.

Answer (score 4):

Well.. if you're asking what I think you're asking, it's as simple as this.
HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr> 
        <td class="color1"></td>
        <td class="color2"></td>
        <td class="color3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td{
   width: 100px;
   height: 20px;
   padding: 0px;
}
.color1{
  background-color: red;
}
.color2{
  background-color: blue;
}
.color3{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

Or something along those lines.

http://jsfiddle.net/waDFz/

Here's what that looks like.  You can edit the height/width/colors/class names.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use grids, like:

```
<div class="my-grid">
<div class="col-1-3">(be yellow)</div>
<div class="col-2-3">(be green)</div>
<div class="col-3-3">(be blue)</div>
</div>
```

Then in CSS

```
.my-grid {
width: 100%;
}
.col-1-3 {
width: 33%;
float: left;
background-color: yellow;
}
.col-2-3 {
width: 33%;
float: left;
background-color: green;
}
.col-3-3 {
width: 33%;
float: left;
background-color: blue;
}
.my-grid:after {
clear:both;
}
```

Be sure to do the my-grid:after part.

Answer (score 0):

i will prefer table over div. try this

```
<table>
<tr width="300px">
<td style="background:#50c690; width:250px;height:25px;"></td><td style="background:#FE6; width:50px;height:25px;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```